# Hibernate Error: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have this error in my code:

```
"Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] con causa raíz
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, 
SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=INVOICESEL2_.CODE_K, DRIVER=4.14.88"
```

I am not able to find the error, I know that the SQL code -206 refers to An object is specified in a context where it is not valid.

My code is this:

```
public InvoiceSeller getSellerByEmail(String email, String debtorCode) {

    String qString = "SELECT d FROM  " + InvoiceSeller.class.getSimpleName() + " d "
            + " INNER JOIN "+ InvoiceSellerContact.class.getSimpleName() + " sc "
            + " ON d.code = sc.invoiceSeller.code AND d.invoiceDebtor.code = sc.invoiceSeller.invoiceDebtor.code "
            + " INNER JOIN "+ Contact.class.getSimpleName() + " c ON sc.contact.id = c.id "
            + " INNER JOIN " + ActiveRegisterMaster.class.getSimpleName() + " a "
            + " ON d.code = a.code AND d.invoiceDebtor.code = a.invoiceDebtor "
            + " WHERE a.tableName = :tablename AND d.invoiceDebtor.code = :debtorCode "
            + " AND c.email = :email AND d.status = :status";


    TypedQuery<InvoiceSeller> query = this.em.createQuery(qString, InvoiceSeller.class);
    System.out.println(qString);

    System.out.println(query.getFirstResult());

    query.setParameter("debtorCode", debtorCode);
    query.setParameter("email", email);
    query.setParameter("tablename", InvoiceSeller.TABLENAME);
    query.setParameter("status", "A");

    InvoiceSeller seller = query.getSingleResult();

    System.out.println(seller.toString());

    return seller;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The **-206** code is `object-name IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED`, please post the generated SQL, you may be using an incorrect field or mapping in your HQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HQL is wrong, remember that HQL sintax is different from SQL and when you call `this.em.createQuery` you are trying to create a HQL.

So, your HQL should be something like this:

```
 String qString = "SELECT d FROM  " + InvoiceSeller.class.getSimpleName() + " d "
            + " INNER JOIN "+ InvoiceSellerContact.class.getSimpleName() + " sc "
            + " INNER JOIN "+ Contact.class.getSimpleName() + " c "
            + " INNER JOIN " + ActiveRegisterMaster.class.getSimpleName() + " a "
            + " WHERE a.tableName = :tablename AND d.invoiceDebtor.code = :debtorCode "
            + " AND c.email = :email AND d.status = :status";
            + " AND c.email = :email AND d.status = :status";
```

Note that i removed the **ON** keywords after INNER JOIN, beacuse HQL don't need it.

Comment: We are using the ON because the ActiveRegisterMaster don't have any relation with InvoiceSeller. Also when we remove the ON we get a 104 error.

Comment: If ActiveRegisterMaster don't have relation with InvoiceSeller you can't make INNER JOIN in HQL, you need a nativeQuery to force it. But i really recommend that you review you mapping beacuse INNER JOIN don't make sense with don't exist relationship. Anyway, you can't use ON keyword in HQL.

Comment: We already used TypedQuery with ActiveRegisterMaster and other unrelated tables, using INNER JOIN and ON and that queries works complety fine